# Java Filter: Writing object to response having "marshalled" format

Tags: json, spring, marshalling, servlet-filters

I am using Spring Delegating proxy filter to do some validations in Filter class before passing on to Controller.  On failed validations i intend to return user defined "ErrorMessage" object in json format, what would be the best way to return json from filter? Is it possible? I tried returning string by writing it in output and it worked fine but i dont seem to able to figure out how to return object and that too in json format

Code Snippet:

```
application context xml -
<bean class="com.company.rest.ValidationFilter" id="validationFilter" />

ValidationFilter -

public class ValidationFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    final String acceptHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Accept");
    if (PAYLOAD_FORMATS.jsonp.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase(acceptHeader)) {
        final OutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        final GenericResponseWrapper wrapper = new GenericResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

    //Some validation
        if (ifValidationFails) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(400);
            httpServletResponse.addHeader("cause", "Required String parameter is not present.");   
            //Need to return this object in response
            final ExceptionWrapper exception = new ExceptionWrapper();
            exception.setErrorMessage("Required String parameter is not present");
            //Returning string works fine 
            outputStream.write(new String("Required String parameter is not present").getBytes());
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

            outputStream.write(new String("test" + "(").getBytes());
            outputStream.write(wrapper.getData());
            outputStream.write(new String(");").getBytes());
        }
        wrapper.setContentType("text/javascript;charset=UTF-8");
        outputStream.close();
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filters are part of the Servlet API which is quite low level - Spring MVC builds on that standard. You don't get all the goodies that the Spring guys have written to automatically serialize POJOs. Although I imagine it would be possible to manually wire together the necessary components necessary to do it.

I suggest looking at the declartive validation that exists using the @Valid annotation in Spring MVC: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation

Comment: I have a situation in which there are couple of parameters that are accepted by all the Restful endpoints and there are multiple validations that have to be done on those params, so i was tending more towards using Filter.